# Problem serializing single quote and double quote into post meta

Tags: post-meta

This is a silly question and I shouldn't have to be spending this much time on this issue. I've been trying all sorts of things without any success.

I am trying to serialize a string with single quotes and double quotes. But no matter how I escape it, I get a corrupted string in my `postmeta` table with **2 extra** characters that aren't there.

```
Pseudocode Example:
    Input: 1234' 1234"
    Output: s:5:"input";s:19:"1234\' 1234&quot;";

Note that the output is actually 17 chars long, not 19.
```

In this example I used `addcslashes( htmlspecialchars ( $input ), '\'\"' );`, I also tried just with `addcslashes` and I still get the extra 2 chars in the serialized string.

After escaping the string, I used php's `serialize` function and wordpress's `update_post_meta` function.

I should also mention that I am running PHP 5.4, so no magic quotes filter applies.

What am I missing here?

Comment: the post meta functions do escaping and serialization for you, why are you doing it manually?

Comment: The data being saved is an array, I have to serialize it before, don't I?

Comment: no, WordPress will take care of that.

Comment: Huh, alright... I will give it a shot now.

Comment: Yep, you are right, thanks! Don't you hate it when you waste so much time on something so stupid... arghhh